# Dealing with numbered variable names MATLAB

Tags: matlab

This is a bit of a long problem:

I am building an extension to some already existing software that outputs data as a structure array each time it is run. They always have the same name (structureArray)

I want to take all of these structure arrays and use them for analysis in a single code with for loops and cell arrays.

So I now have 3 structure arrays from this existing software, which I have named structureArray1, structureArray2 and structureArray3. I have used the following method for putting each of these into a cell array called "storage".

```
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile('*.mat','Please select your structure     arrays',...
    'Multiselect','on');

storage = cell(1,numel(filename));

for x = 1 : numel(filename)
    storage{x} = load([pathname filename{x}]);
end
```

Now here's the problem:

in each structureArray(1,2,3) (now within "storage") there is a matrix called "magV". I would like to have a 1x3 cell array, with the first cell containing magV from structureArray1, the second cell containing magV from structureArray2 and so on...

My attempt so far:

```
magnitude_V = cell(1,numel(storage));

for y = 1 : numel(storage)
    magnitude_V{y} = storage{1,y}.structureArray1.velocityMap.magV;
end
```

But because all of the structure arrays have a different number at the end, I can't use this method...

Thank you so much for any help because this is driving me mad -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to a structure's fied by a string in parenthesis, e.g. `sometruct.('somefield')`:

```
magnitude_V = cell(1,size(storage,2));

for y = 1 : size(storage,2)
    magnitude_V{y} = storage{y}.(['structureArray' num2str(y)]).velocityMap.magV;
end
```